# Read and modify objects in a generic List<T>

Tags: c#, list

I am working with a generic List which I add Employee objects to.
I know how to add and remove from it, but how do I "read" object data from it and how do I access methods and properties for a specific object in the list.

Let's say the `Employee` class contains the property below, how do I access it to modify the objects data?

```
public string FirstNameData
{
   get { return v_firstName; }
   set { v_firstName = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming:

```
var myList = new List<Employee>();
```

You have many options here...

First, you can index it directly:

```
var firstName = myList[0].FirstNameData
```

You can enumerate over it:

```
foreach(var employee in myList)
  ProcessName(employee.FirstNameData);
```

If you are using .Net 3.5 or greater, you can use Linq exetnsions:

```
var firstName = myList.First().FirstNameData;
var allFirstNames = myList.Select(employee => employee.FirstNameData);
```

It all depends on what you want to do...

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through the list and edit them, e.g.

```
public void KnightEmployees(List<Employee> employeeList)
{
    foreach(Employee employee in employeeList)
    {
        if (employee.Gender == Gender.Male)
        {
            employee.FirstNameData = "Sir " + employee.FirstNameData;
        }
        else
        {
            employee.FirstNameData = "Dame " + employee.FirstNameData;
        }
    }
}
```

or access them by index in the list which gives you an object you can use as normal, e.g.

```
employeeList[0].FirstNameData = "Bob";
```

Is that the sort of thing you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for indexes?

```
List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
list[0] = new Employee();
list[0].FirstNameData = "John";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly what you're asking, but if you know which employee in the list you want, your code would probably look something like this:

```
var emps = new List<Employee>();
emps.Add(...);
...
Console.WriteLine(emps[3].FirstName); //the 4th employee in the list
```

And this is somewhat unrelated to your question, but you may want to try making your properties a bit more brief by using automatic properties (which don't require a private backing variable) in C# like so:

```
public string FirstNameData {
   get; set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you are trying to reach the value where the property is contained in a generic list. This is my take;

Assuming:

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
```

Let's say you don't know which index your property is contained in, after all it could be anything.

First, you'd search over the List to see where it's contained:

```
     Employee emp = new Employee();
    int foundIndex = employeeList.FindIndex(i => i.v_firstName == emp.v_firstName); 
// the FindIndex method searches over the list and returns an integer where the v_firstName field is located in.
```

We have found where your property was located in, now it's time to modify it.

```
employeeList[foundIndex].v_firstName = "example";
```

Let me know if anyone is still having a trouble.